# Laravel Homestead mapped folders not available in VM

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I want to use Laravel's pre-packaged Vagrant box Homestead for my local development environment. However, I'm running into a problem where the configured folders from my Mac don't sync up with the folders in my VM. Here's my Homestead.yaml

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/dev/Web/Yoosit
      to: /home/vagrant/Code

sites:
    - map: yoosit.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/Yoosit/public

databases:
    - homestead

variables:
    - key: 'APP_ENV'
      value: 'local'
    - key: 'APP_DEBUG'
      value: 'true'

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

There are simply no folders available in my vm. When I `ls -l` in `/home/vagrant`.

EDIT Boot output

```
Roemers-MacBook-Pro:.homestead roemerbakker$ vagrant halt
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
Roemers-MacBook-Pro:.homestead roemerbakker$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'laravel/homestead' is up to date...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => /Users/roemerbakker/.homestead
==> default: Machine already provisioned. Run `vagrant provision` or use the `--provision`
==> default: flag to force provisioning. Provisioners marked to run always will still run.
```

Comment: Could you show the terminal output you get when booting up the VM?

Comment: @Tim Done, nothing special

Comment: It looks like it doesn't even try to mount your specified folders. Assuming you modified the correct yaml within `~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml` I would say you booted the VM up and added your shared folders later. Try to reboot the machine with `vagrant up --provision` to reprovision the machine.

Comment: @Tim Thanks. It does seem I'm editing the right file. If it's not the file in `~/.homestead/Homestead.yaml`, do you have any idea what file it could be? I've provisioned my VM several times.

Comment: Did you have provisioned your VM with the `--provision` flag to force provisioning?

Comment: @Tim I just did and the logs say `==> default: Mounting shared folders...` now but the folder is still not available.

Comment: And in the next line it says `default: /vagrant => /Users/roemerbakker/.homestead` which is a mounted folder. And I'm wondering where that comes from…

Comment: @Tim I know right. A teammate just suggested to reinstall everything as he had the same problem. Basically, vagrant is a bit shitty.

Comment: Can't say that for myself, everything works fine. In which folder did you install Homestead? It looks like you cloned the repo into `.homestead`, that could be a problem.

Comment: @Tim Yeah I'm sure it's lovely when it actually works. It's cloned in `~/Homestead` but `~/.homestead` was created when I did the init stuff.

Comment: @Tim Destoying it WORKED